# Weather information on the notification pull-down is useless

Tags: notifications, ios

For example, it's nearly midnight now.  Look at the information I am provided.

[image: weather information]

Is there any way I can have it show **useful** information instead, like perhaps...

- the low tonight
- the temperature tomorrow morning
- will it be rainy tomorrow?
- the high tomorrow afternoon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in weather information is pretty lame and has no settings associated with it. That said, you should look into other weather widgets that you can install and display instead of the iOS-supplied info:

http://9to5mac.com/2014/09/26/ios-8-weather-widgets-best/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know other apps could put things in the notification center

Comment: Happy hunting, Lakey!